# Пересечение прямоугольников

Tags: objective-c

Есть 2 прямоугольника со сторонами параллельными осям координат. Прямоугольники задаются координатами левого нижнего угла и шириной и высотой. Нужно определить третий прямоугольник, который является пересечением первых двух. Необходимо использовать классы. 
Если проверять все условия, то получается очень сложный метод  и громоздкий. Подскажите решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод получается не сложный и не громоздкий. Всего 2 шага.

1. Проверить, пересекаются ли прямоугольники = одновременно пересекаются их проекции на оси OX и OY.
2. Если есть пересечение, то найти результирующий прямоугольник = максимальные X и Y левых нижних углов, минимальные X и Y правых верхних углов.

Реализовать это в методе класса прямоугольника - не проблема, причем можно каждый шаг в виде отдельного метода.

Answer (score 4):

Если я Вас верно понял, то функция CGRectIntersection должна помочь. Документация гласит:

> A rectangle that represents the
> intersection of the two specified
> rectangles. If the two rectangles do
> not intersect, returns the null
> rectangle. To check for this
> condition, use CGRectIsNull.

Если так уж необходимо использовать классы и работой со структурой CGRect никак не ограничиться, то всегда можно написать класс-обертку вокруг CGRect, внутри которой использовать указанную функцию.

Answer (score 0):

а почему не использовать готовый метод: `CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2)`?
также можно получить прямоугольник пересечения `CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(rect1, rect2);`